# Media Foundation H.264 High CPU Usage

Tags: c#, h.264, ms-media-foundation, hardware-acceleration

I got High CPU Usage writing the stream on the sink in Media Foundation .Net. Below is how I initialize the sinkwriter.

```
private int InitializeSinkWriter(String outputFile, int videoWidth, int videoHeight)
    {
        IMFMediaType mediaTypeIn = null;
        IMFMediaType mediaTypeOut = null;
        IMFAttributes attributes = null;

        int hr = 0;

        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateAttributes(out attributes, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)attributes.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_LOW_LATENCY, 1);

        // Create the sink writer 
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(outputFile, null, attributes, out sinkWriter);

        // Create the output type
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out mediaTypeOut);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType.MPEG4);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.H264);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, videoBitRate);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, (int)MFVideoInterlaceMode.Progressive);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeSize(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeOut, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.AddStream(mediaTypeOut, out streamIndex);

        // Create the input type 
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out mediaTypeIn);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Video);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.RGB32);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)mediaTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, (int)MFVideoInterlaceMode.Progressive);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeSize(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, videoWidth, videoHeight);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFSetAttributeRatio(mediaTypeIn, MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, mediaTypeIn, null);


        // Start accepting data
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.BeginWriting();


        COMBase.SafeRelease(mediaTypeOut);
        COMBase.SafeRelease(mediaTypeIn);


        return hr;
    }
```

and this is how a add sample on the sinkwriter.

```
 IMFSample sample = null;
        IMFMediaBuffer buffer = null;


        IntPtr data = new IntPtr();
        int bufferMaxLength;
        int bufferCurrentLength;

        int hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateMemoryBuffer(frameSizeBytes, out buffer);

        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)buffer.Lock(out data, out bufferMaxLength, out bufferCurrentLength);
        if (Succeeded(hr))
        {
                hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCopyImage(
                    data,                                       // Destination buffer.
                    videoWidth * BYTES_PER_PIXEL,               // Destination stride.
                    (IntPtr)(frame.frame.DataPointer + (videoHeight - 1) * frame.frame.RowPitch),                    // First row in source image.
                    -frame.frame.RowPitch,                       // Source stride.
                    videoWidth * BYTES_PER_PIXEL,               // Destination stride.
                    videoHeight                                 // Image height in pixels
                    );
        }

        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)buffer.Unlock();
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)buffer.SetCurrentLength(frameSizeBytes);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateSample(out sample);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sample.AddBuffer(buffer);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sample.SetSampleTime(frame.prevRecordingDuration);
        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sample.SetSampleDuration((frame.recordDuration-frame.prevRecordingDuration));

        if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.WriteSample(streamIndex, sample);

        COMBase.SafeRelease(sample);
        COMBase.SafeRelease(buffer);
```

When I comment out the `if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.WriteSample(streamIndex, sample);`

The CPU got only 10% below but when I activated the writesample it goes up to 50%. Can anyone help me How to use the hardware encode? Thanks I'm using c#.

Comment: You need to add Direct3D 9 or 11 texture samples. Created by you or allocated by an IMFVideoSampleAllocator(Ex). Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530112(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes I'm feeding the writer with directx texture. I can produce a video without getting problem except High CPU usage. I tried changing H.264 to NV12 but my output file became large almost 1 gig and unplayable.

Comment: No, you are not. You use MFCreateMemoryBuffer.

Comment: Hi,I'm sorry but I'm new in Direct X programming. This is what I passed on my frame.frame varibale 
device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);
and I can't figure out how can I implement your suggestion as it's my first time working in this kind of application. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately MFCreateDXSurfaceBuffer is not available on Mediafoundation.Net The wrapper of that code is not yet implemented. Is there any work around on this?

Comment: Make a managed c++ assembly that utilizes MFCreateDXSurfaceBuffer or IMFVideoSampleAllocator(Ex).

Comment: Okay I have now wrapper for MFCreateDXSurfaceBuffer and using this code  MFExtern.MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D).GUID, frame1.surface, 0, true, out buffer); where frame1.surface is equivalent to screenTexture.QueryInterface<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(); but I produced 0 bytes of mp4 file. I used MFExtern.MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface(null,out sample); to create sample and sample.AddBuffer(buffer); to add the buffer.

Comment: I got E_NOINTERFACE when executing MFExtern.MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11‌​.Texture2D).GUID, frame1.surface, 0, true, out buffer);

Comment: I'm not sure what typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11‌​‌​.Texture2D returns but in C++ the first param should be IID_ID3D11Texture2D or __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D).

Comment: SharpDX.Direct3D11‌​‌​.Texture2D return ID3D11Texture2D. I've searched on the net and __uuidof of c++ is equivalent to typeof().GUID in c#.

Comment: here is the Texture2d Code https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct3D11/Texture2D.cs

Comment: "I've searched on the net and __uuidof of c++ is equivalent to typeof().GUID in c#". I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay Thank you for the answer.You helped me alot. I think I should raise another question about the equivalent code of __uuidof to c#.

Comment: I can confirmed that Texture2D returns the GUID of ID3D11Texture2D and I found it inside my  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\d3d11.idl. However I cant still be able to make MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer work. still giving me E_NOINTERFACE.

Comment: Try to hardcode the IID_ID3D11Texture2D as suggested in your other question.

Comment: Yes I already did but no luck. Gave me the same error.